# find the list of hidden elements using selenium with java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am trying to fetch all elements using findelements method. However, it is getting only visible elements rather than all hidden elements. Could anyone please suggest how to get the list of all hidden elements using javascript executor or something?

**Code**:

```
List<WebElement> allInputElements = ldriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='card-title']"));
    if(allInputElements.size() != 0)
    {
           System.out.println(allInputElements.size() + " List of Video in carousal swiper: \n");
            
           for(WebElement inputElement : allInputElements) 
           {
               System.out.println(inputElement.getText());
           }
       }
```

**Actual**:
Out of 11 elements i can see only 4 element name.

Comment: How are the elements hidden? There are many methods to do so.

Comment: It is kind of swiping banner and user can only view  4 banners. If i click an left  arrow user could view some more banners. Elements are hiding in this manner

Comment: In the HTML/DOM, how is it? You can copy the code on the question itself

Comment: Share the HTML and related CSS, JS so that we can try to replicate and then find a solution.